# PHP curl soap - get variable

Tags: php, arrays, xml, curl, soap

I have seen multiple posts on this subject but it seems everyone I have tried doesn't return a variable. All I'm trying to do is return the SessionIdentifier and SessionIdentifierHash. Below is the code I am trying.

```
$soapresults = <<< LOL
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="09c896dd-59d9-4cdf-82db-41b8ffed6400"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">ded007e7-c496-4ec6-8596-4a302f12b446</ActivityId>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <ResponseOf_PublicLoginResult xmlns="http://schemas.sendwordnow.com/ws/2010/05/PublicSessionManager">
      <OperationResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SWN.Notification.PublicSessionManagement.Contracts.DataContracts"
      xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:IsSuccess>true</a:IsSuccess>
        <a:ResultCode>Success</a:ResultCode>
        <a:ResultDescription>Successfull login.</a:ResultDescription>
        <a:SessionToken xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SWN.Framework.SessionState">
          <b:SessionIdentifier>265277237</b:SessionIdentifier>
          <b:SessionIdentifierHash>
          2dSXW81GQxNy1iYzRlLTRjZjItYjYyNS01MmEyZDM5M2RlMjI=</b:SessionIdentifierHash>
        </a:SessionToken>
        <a:Username>myapiusername</a:Username>
        <a:PartnerId>1</a:PartnerId>
        <a:PasswordExpiredAfter>-1</a:PasswordExpiredAfter>
        <a:QuickSendExpiredAfter>-1</a:QuickSendExpiredAfter>
      </OperationResult>
    </ResponseOf_PublicLoginResult>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
LOL;
$soap = simplexml_load_string($soapresults);
$soap->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://schemas.sendwordnow.com/ws/2010/05/PublicSessionManager');
$test = (string) $soap->xpath('//ns1:OperationResult/ns1:IsSuccess');
var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there are more namespaced elements in the response. So, you need to keep using `registerXPathNamespace()` throughout the iteration. There's probably a better way, though:

```
$soap = simplexml_load_string($soapresults);
$soap->registerXPathNamespace('ns1', 'http://schemas.sendwordnow.com/ws/2010/05/PublicSessionManager');
$test = $soap->xpath('//ns1:OperationResult');
foreach ($test as $el) {
    $el->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SWN.Notification.PublicSessionManagement.Contracts.DataContracts');
    $el2 = $el->xpath("//ns2:SessionToken");
    foreach ($el2 as $val) {
        $val->registerXPathNamespace('ns3', 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SWN.Framework.SessionState');
        $sessionIdentifier = $val->xPath("//ns3:SessionIdentifier")[0];
        $sessionIdentifierHash = $val->xPath("//ns3:SessionIdentifierHash")[0];
    }
}
echo "Identifier: ".$sessionIdentifier." - Hash: ". $sessionIdentifierHash;
```

Result:

> Identifier: 265277237 - Hash
>             2dSXW81GQxNy1iYzRlLTRjZjItYjYyNS01MmEyZDM5M2RlMjI=

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/RhXFc)

Notice that the `SessionIdentifierHash` has some whitespace around it. I don't know if this is the intention of the response.

Comment: Yep that works! I added the extra space by accident in my editor. So that's a good to go.

Comment: Glad to hear! Why did you delete your other comment? That was a way better way to go at it! I don't know why I stuck with `simplexml_load_string()`, `DOMDocument` was a better way. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I also found this that also works so not sure if this is a better way.

```
$soap_response = $soapresults;
$dom_result = new DOMDocument;
if (!$dom_result->loadXML($soap_response))
    throw new Exception(_('Error parsing response'), 11);
    $my_val = $dom_result->getElementsByTagName('SessionIdentifier')->item(0)->nodeValue;
var_dump($my_val);
```